# How to fit text with specific length giving by getComputedTextLength to specified length in SVG

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, d3.js

Im new in typescript and svg and d3, So I have this code

```
this.main
            .selectAll(this.appCssConstants.sliceLabel.selectorName)
            .data(root)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .style("fill", "blue")
            .classed(this.appCssConstants.sliceLabel.className, true)
            // font size + slice padding
            .attr("dy", (d, i) => {
                return labelshift - d.depth * labelshiftmulti;
            })
            .append("textPath")
            .attr("startOffset", "50%")
            .attr("xlink:href", (d, i) => "#sliceLabel_" + i)
            .text(dataPoint => dataPoint.data.name)
            .attr("textLength")
            .each(this.wrapPathText(labelPadding));
```

...

```
  private wrapPathText(padding?: number): (slice: HierarchyRectangularNode<SunburstDataPoint>, index: number) => void {
        const self = this;
        return function () {
            const selection: Selection<BaseType, any, BaseType, any> = d3Select(this);
            const width = (<SVGPathElement>d3Select(selection.attr("xlink:href")).node()).getTotalLength();
            self.wrapText(selection, padding, width);
        };
    }

    private wrapText(selection: Selection<BaseType, any, BaseType, any>, padding?: number, width?: number): void {
        let node: SVGTextElement = <SVGTextElement>selection.node(),
            textLength: number = node.getComputedTextLength(),
            text: string = selection.text();
        width = width || 0;
        padding = padding || 0;
        while (textLength > (width - 2 * padding) && text.length > 0) {
            text = text.slice(0, -1);
            selection.text(text + "\u2026");
            textLength = node.getComputedTextLength();
        }
        if (textLength > (width - 2 * padding)) {
            selection.text("");
        }
    }
```

I have a loop ".each" in first part of the code that calls method wrapPathText
and wrapPathText have a for loop that takes long long time in the loop for slicing text

My question is - Is there a way to optimize this loop? For  example removing more than one letter in each loopto fit the string?
Another question - Is there a way to fit a string with specific giving length (in my case 'width - 2 * padding') for example by the help of a specific attribute without using the unoptimized for loop?